# Updating Kivy's display

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to update the display with new contents. I am using Builder.load_string() to load the contents. The first time the application runs, it displays the contents correctly. However, when new contents are available, Builder.load_string() returns None and add_widget() displays "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fbind'".
To keep things simple, I am updating the display with the same contents as a static string. here is my code:

```
import kivy
import time
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock,mainthread
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

kivy.require('1.9.0')

KV='''
<Example>:
     Label:
         text:'hello'
     Label:
         text:'world'
'''

@mainthread
def update(dt):
    try:
       vRoot = App.get_running_app().root
       vRoot.clear_widgets()
       Builder.unload_file('file.kv')
       v=Builder.load_string(KV,filename='file.kv')
       print(v)
       vRoot.add_widget(v)
    except BaseException as e:
       print (str(e))

def loop():
    time.sleep(5)
    Clock.schedule_once(update)

Builder.load_string(KV,filename='file.kv')

class Example(BoxLayout):
      pass

class MyApp(App):
      def build(self):
          return Example()

vThread=threading.Thread(target=loop)
vThread.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   MyApp().run()
```

Thank you

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: I added the import statements. you can now run it as is to see the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your kv-string doesn't contain any root widget except the design. That's why upon loading this return `None` and `None` can't be added as a widget.

For the first time you returned `Example` from method `build` which was used as the `root`. But second time you happen to add `None` as `root`.

Here's a modification to your code that does update with newly defined rule.

```py
.
.
.
KV='''

<Example>:
    Label:
        text:'hello'
    Label:
        text:'world'
'''

new_rule='''

NewExample:

<NewExample@BoxLayout>:
    Button:
        text:'hello'
    Button:
        text:'world'
'''

@mainthread
def update(dt):
    try:
       vRoot = App.get_running_app().root
       vRoot.clear_widgets()
#       Builder.unload_file('file.kv')
#       v=Builder.load_string(KV,filename='file.kv')
       v = Builder.load_string(new_rule)
       print(v)
       vRoot.add_widget(v)
    except BaseException as e:
       print(str(e))

def loop():
    # Use clock instead of time.sleep.
#    time.sleep(5)
    Clock.schedule_once(update, 5.0)
.
.
.
```

Comment: thank you very much for your time and experience. What I don't understand is that the kv-string did not change between the first and second load. the first load returned a correct Example object, but the second load returned None. why? I am sorry I am new to both Python and Kivy.

Comment: I've already tried to explain that in the answer. You can find more in doc of [`build`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.build) and that of [`kvlang`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#overview).